# ASP.NET Core EF Identity - Trying to seed city and country data into separate tables, setting PK doesn't work

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, identity

I'm trying to make an initial seed of country- and city- names into my db which has a 1-to-many relationship between the tables. Setting the PK (eg CityId = 1) doesn't add the post to the db. However, leaving the PK out adds the post to the db, but gives it an incremented Id, as expected, but will break the relation coupling of country-city. MS says that you should always include the Id due to migration updates and so on, but what am I missing here? Searched for days and only gets back to the same info as from MS.

```
public static void Initialize(AppIdentityDbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.Migrate(); ;

        // Add sample countries
        var countries = new Country[]
        {
        //Works
        new Country{CountryName="Sweden"},
        //Doesn't work
        new Country{CountryID = 1, CountryName="Sweden"},

        };
        foreach (Country s in countries)
        {
            context.Countries.Add(s);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What do your entities look like?  Did you map the CountryID with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Comment: They are just 'Id' and 'Name' for each table. No mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the CountryID and CityID from the seed, as it is done during the init process to a newly created db, so the auto incremented Id's works fine.